# number pattern programs in java

Tags: java

How to print the triangle below:

```
2  3  5  8  3  8
   4  6  9  4  9
      7  1  5  1
         2  6  2
            7  3
               4
```

First you need to start with number 2 and add one to the next one vertically

My code:

```
        int d = 2, n = 6;
        for (int line=1; line <= n; line++ ) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= line; j++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for (int k = line; k <= n; k++) {
                System.out.print(d + " ");
                    d = d + k;
                    if (d > 9) {
                        d = d - 9;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Result:

```
2 3 5 8 3 8 
  5 7 1 5 1 
    7 1 5 1 
      7 2 7 
        4 9 
          6
```

Comment: After you break the line d has the incorrect value. Try to fix that. (You already know how to calculate the values of the 1st line, so all you need to do is adjust it for the line you are about to print)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is that the value of `d` has to be **calculated initially on every new line** based on the value of `d` in the **first instance of the previous line**. That is the part that's missed here. You can do that by having a temp variable store the initial value of `d` on every line and print based on that. I have used a variable `tempD` here, which can help print the pattern that you require.

```
    int d = 2, n = 6;
    int tempD = d - 1;
    for (int line = 1; line <= n; line++) {
        tempD = tempD + line;
        if (tempD > 9) {
            tempD = tempD - 9;
        }
        d = tempD;
        for (int j = 2; j <= line; j++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int k = line; k <= n; k++) {
            System.out.print(d + " ");
            d = d + k;
            if (d > 9) {
                d = d - 9;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```